# How to place words in a word cloud as per its occurrence in R?

Tags: r, word-cloud

I am working on a *word cloud* using the word cloud package wherein I want the words to appear in the same order as in the sentence/text. I only know the `random.order` - which plots words in random order. If false, they will be plotted in decreasing frequency.
My usage:

```
comparison.cloud(term.matrix,max.words=300)
commonality.cloud(term.matrix,random.order=FALSE, rot.per=0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the comparison.cloud function source code (just call it without parens). You will see the following code block somewhere.

```
if (random.order) {
    ord <- sample.int(length(words))
}
else {
    ord <- order(freq, decreasing = TRUE)
}
```

You can create your own copy of the function and tinker with how this ord vector is constructed to change the way things are ordered to match your use-case exactly. I would just try removing this block altogether initially and see what happens!

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply and sorry for the delay in response. I tried removing the block still the same. Is there any other way to achieve this?  I am new to R so a descriptive answer would be of great help.